# perl how to search excel worksheet being case insensitive

Tags: perl, case-sensitive

current script:

```
$ws = $wb->Worksheet("Food_List");

if ( !$ws ) {
    print LOG
        "Error: Required 'Food_List' excel spreadsheet(tab). Review worksheet naming convention";
    exit 1;
}
```

so now we need to match the worksheet to 'Food_List'. What if I want to allow more flexibility and allow 'food_list', or 'FOOD_LIST'worksheet?

Comment: Which module are you using? What you need to do is enumerate the available worksheets, and then pick one that closest matches your search term.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're using `Spreadsheet::ParseExcel`:

```
my $ws;
for my $sheet ( $wb->worksheets() ) {
    if ( $sheet->get_name() =~ m/Food_list/i ) {
        $ws = $sheet;
        last;
    }
}
```

Update: Use get_name and it works.

Comment: yes,  using Spreadsheet::ParseExcel. but it doesnt get into the if condition

Comment: the flow doesn't go into the if condition

Comment: Are there any worksheets? If you `print $sheet -> name` outside the `if` does that do anything?

Comment: yes there are two worksheets. one matches the Food_list, one does not.
nothing is printed from $sheet -> name